# How to find a string in a Column in a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to find a fast way to find a string in a Column in a DataTable and add it to a comboBox, and this is the code i tried so far :

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Id_Editeur ID,Libelle_Editeur Editeur from Editeur", myClass.cnx);
            adapter.Fill(myClass.ds, "Editeur");
            foreach (String str in myClass.ds.Tables["Editeur"].Columns[1].ToString())
                editeurBox.Properties.Items.Add(str);
```

and that's doesn't work it gives me this error :

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Data.DataColumn' because 'System.Data.DataColumn' does not
>   contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

How can I do that ? (I don't want the for loop solution).

Comment: What is wrong with that `for` thing...?

Comment: I just want another solution because I already knows how to do it using the for loop, I'm asking if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach (var row in myClass.ds.Tables["Editeur"].AsEnumerable())
{
    editeurBox.Properties.Items.Add(row[1].ToString());
}
```

or Full linq-style:

```
editeurBox.Properties.Items.AddRange(
    myClass.ds.Tables["Editeur"]
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Select(dr => dr[1].ToString()
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try with this code - based on `LINQ Field operator`

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<string>("RowNo") == "yourSearch"
select myRow;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to loop through the rows and grab the column that you want. Your code is trying to loop through the column collection which doesn't contain any data:

```
foreach (DataRow row in myClass.ds.Tables["Editeur"].Rows)
                    editeurBox.Properties.Items.Add(row[1].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        string TableSelect;
        DataTable dt = GetSomeData();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            TableSelect = "EmplNo = " + row["EmplNo"].ToString();
            DataRow[] foundrows;
            foundrows = dt.Select(TableSelect);
            if (foundrows.Count() > 0)
            {
                //do something useful here :)
            }
        }
```